# Kubernetes Service Discovery DNS lookup

Tags: kubernetes, dns, minikube, service-discovery

When I do nslookup on a kubernetes service , it resolves , but it also throws some errors on additional name lookups , how can I disable this? How can I tell service discovery not to lookup those additional names.

```
/ # nslookup mysql
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10:53

Name:   mysql.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.101.121.224

*** Can't find mysql.svc.cluster.local: No answer
*** Can't find mysql.cluster.local: No answer
*** Can't find mysql.default.svc.cluster.local: No answer
*** Can't find mysql.svc.cluster.local: No answer
*** Can't find mysql.cluster.local: No answer
```

and I do a specific search, it just fails:

```
/ # nslookup mysql.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10:53


*** Can't find mysql.default.svc.cluster.local: No answer

/ #
```

Comment: What's inside /etc/resolv.conf ?

Comment: the same standard settings that you will find in any minikube deployment

Comment: Does it work fine with default svc `nslookup kubernetes.default` ?